# Firing of asynchronous (statistics) request of HyperlinkButton not registered

Tags: c#, silverlight, hyperlink, silverlight-3.0, firebug

I have a HyperlinkButton in my Silverlight project. Clicking the link will open the URL in a new page:

```
<HyperlinkButton x:Name="Button1" Content="Click" 
  TargetName="_blank" Click="Button1_Click" 
  NavigateUri="http://www.example.com" />
```

When I click the button, I want a (second) asynchronous request to be fired to a statistics server:

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
   webClient.Headers["content-type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
   webClient.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
   webClient.UploadStringAsync(destURI, "POST", "action=click" + 
       "&id=" + id);
}
```

However, if I check with FireBug, this request is never fired. How can I make this request work?

Note: I have already checked that the destination page can receive requests. The destination has a correct `clientaccesspolicy.xml` and `crossdomain.xml`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Argh. The problem is with Firebug. The browser window loses focus and requests are no longer captured. Wireshark shows that the request fires correctly.

Answer (score 0):

`NavigateUri` seems to take precedence over firing the event handler for `Click`, so what you would need to do is remove the `NavigateUri`, and handle everything inside the `Click` event itself.

You can use the `HtmlPage.Window.Navigate()` function to spawn a new window by setting the target to `_blank`, much like you did in the XAML for `HyperlinkButton`.

Comment: I did this before. This seems to fire the popup blocker of Firefox. Using NavigateUri doesn't.
Moreover, attaching the Visual Studio debugger tells me the click method is called, so I really don't know why I don't see the request.